# Using boost memory pool with a class with vectors as member variables

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to use boost::object_pool to allocate memory to objects of a type that contains vectors as member variables.

```
class X{
std::vector<Type> v1;
std::vector<Type> v2;

int a;
double b;
..
};


void func()
{
      boost::object_pool<X> p;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
      {
        X * const t = p.malloc();

      }
}
```

Now the constructor of boost::object_pool uses sizeof(X) to find the size of X and so it has no way to find out that the member variables v1 and v2 will grow at run time.

1. I am guessing that it may lead to copying of the object to a different location, which will lead to a performance penalty rather than speeding it up which was the purpose of using memory pool. Is my guess correct? If no, what else will happen when v1 and v2 grow at run time?
2. How are member variables of the type vector (or any other type that grows at run time) laid down in memory? Does the object contains pointer to vector in the heap rather than the vector itself? How do I make sure that when the vectors grow, they use memory from a pool?
3. I am creating lots of objects of the type X at run time. Is boost::object_pool the appropriate interface to use in this scenario?If not how else shall I be approaching this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

sizeof(v1) and sizeof(v2) won't grow at runtime. They use pointers and heap allocation internally.

Pools are appropriate if you need to allocate lots of objects of the same type, and be able to quickly delete them all at once.

Comment: Yes, I am allocating lots of objects of the same type. How do I make sure that when the vectors grow, they use memory from a pool?

Comment: boost also has a fast_pool_allocator to be used by vector. it may improve perf if you're allocating and deleting lots of vectors over and over. vector is already very efficient, so i would be careful and measure this.

Answer (score 2):

You have some incorrect assumptions. Because the underlying array in `std::vector` is on the heap, the `sizeof()` never changes. There shouldn't be any copying at all in `boost::object_pool`. As for whether that's the right choice for you, that depends on how often you plan on creating and destroying `X` objects.